# Import data directly from Excel sheet into SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, excel, c#-4.0, import-from-excel

I have multiple table's data in single Excel sheet with exact column names, now I want to insert that data into my SQL Server 2008 tables.

For example: I have one table `Student` which has columns `Stud_ID, Stud_Name, Branch, Status`.

And same as, I have one Excel sheet `Student` which has columns `Stud_ID, Stud_Name, Branch, Status`. Excel sheet has multiple records of data in it.

Now I want to insert that data into the SQL Server table `Student`.

How can I do that using C# coding and without coding (directly Excel to SQL Server database)? Please guide me its urgent.

Thanks.

Comment: Answers with help of C# coding or without help of Coding are acceptable. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Hello All, Actually I did not try anything before this post because I did not know anything about direct as well as coding through import of data from excel into data table. But now I successfully achieved that through C# Code mention in answer below by Niladri.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [Import Data from excel to SQL server using C# in ASP. NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/300639/Import-Data-from-excel-to-SQL-server-using-Csharp) for doing the same using C#

check [How to import an Excel file into SQL Server 2005 using Integration Services](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/datacenter/how-to-import-an-excel-file-into-sql-server-2005-using-integration-services/205) for directly importing Excel data to Sql Server.

Comment: Thanks Niladri, But one question: With this solution can I insert data in multiple data tables of SQL database at a time?

Comment: offcourse yes ! you can use 'stored procedures' to do so, instead of simple sql query.